# How to get user info from Google OAuth2

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

Google is mandating an upgrade to their authentication/authorization mechanism, deprecating their existing mechanism.

The entire "GoogleAuth" object and all methods is deprecated.

The migration guidelines provide old->new guidance and examples (many of which don't work as described, but that's another story).

The old GoogleAuth object had one particularly necessary method .getUserInfo().

The docs do not provide a migration path for most methods on this object, and not for this one. (The migration doc merely says "remove" with regard to this method.) None of the sample code in migration offer guidance for this.

There is a companion set of docs that describe a different code path, that seems not-entirely-compatible with the new Google Identity Service, and which suggests the user data is embedded in a JWT, but offers no guidance on how to decrypt that JWT.

My code for authenticating, authorizing, and accessing google's api's is more or less functional (still pops a dialog on every new page load, still working on that), but getting the user info has defeated me after scrutinizing every migration doc, code sample, and considerable searching.

Has anyone cracked this nut?

I am terribly afraid that the answer is so simple that I have spent a full day banging my head on my own stupidity.

I'm even more afraid it's not possible!

Comment: What are you following exactly this?  [Sign In With Google JavaScript API reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference)  what are your issues?

Comment: Noted on the answer below; I primarily need authorization, so I was using the authorization code flow. But when I checked out that documentation, I didn't know which of the many JWT options I needed to employ to decode the credentials response. Anyway, I think Morfinismo got to the heart of it for me. Thansk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I understand your frustration but your "question" is more about expressing your frustration instead of explaining what you've done so far so we can help you. However, let me try to provide as much help as possible.

As you already find out, the "Google Identity Services" is separating "Authorization" and "Authentication" into two different things. (In my personal opinion, this makes it harder for us developers, although they[google] claim is more secure but I don't see that).

I presume that you need the "Authentication" part since you need the user information. In that case, you have to follow the guide [documented here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference).

If you will be using the "Sign In With Google" button or the "One Tap" prompt, is up to you. I decided to go with the "One Tap" prompt. Once you get back the credentials response, you have to decode the JWT that comes in the response. There are many JWT libraries you can use, for the purpose of this example, I am using this one: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.20/jsrsasign-all-min.js`, however is your responsibility to find a secure library that allows you to do that, hence Google is not recommending any.

Here is an example of the code I'm using:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.20/jsrsasign-all-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div id="signinBox"></div>
  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js`

```
window.onload = function () {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: 'blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    callback: handleCredentialResponse,
    ux_mode: "redirect",
    prompt_parent_id: "signinBox",
    context: "signin",
    cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
    auto_select: true
  });
  google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
    if(notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
      console.log("Prompt cancelled by user");
    }
  });
};

const handleCredentialResponse = (credsResponse)=>{
  console.log(credsResponse);
  var headerObj  = KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(b64utoutf8(credsResponse.credential.split(".")[0]));
  var payloadObj  = KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(b64utoutf8(credsResponse.credential.split(".")[1]));
  console.log(headerObj);
  console.log(payloadObj);
};
```

After running the above example, you will see the user information in the "payloadObj". It should have all the information as [explained here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#CredentialResponse).

Comment: Thanks; this looks useful. I will test this later in order to mark this as the correct answer. You have answered two of my questions, that their documentation did very poorly. Primarily I need authorization, so I was not doing any of the sign-in flows. This is weird, because it pops up the same dialogs that sign in used to. So I thought I would have access to user data. But I see now that this is not so.

Comment: Additionally, you have given me guidance on how to decode the JWT, which Google does *not* do in their documentation. I get that it's a third party solution, but I installed a couple of different JWT libraries -- and learned that there are many different options for decrypting a JWT, and many of them looked like they needed a key. Other posts on stack overflow discussed without resolution what key to use. Your example is not using any key! So... this looks very helpful. I'll be able to confirm in a couple of hours.

Comment: Finally: this in no way makes my life as a developer easier, and I have reported many deficiencies in their documentation to them. I am very disappointed in the way they are rolling this out. We've gone from one library with a somewhat convoluted code flow to two libraries, three distinct code flows, all with overlapping areas of concern. So, while yes, my frustration is quite present, I did have a very specific question, and you helped me out with it!